# Bootstrap 3 cover homepage (full screen) first section

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullscreen, cover

i am using Bootstrap 3 for my site template. The structure of my homepage will look like

```
<nav>
<section 1>
<section 2>
<section 3>
<footer>
```

`<section 1>` has to be full screen, cover the whole screen. When you scroll down you will see `<section 2>`, `<section 3>` etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: show me what you have tried

Comment: Use `container-fluid`

Comment: show us what you've tried..

Comment: i have [this so far](http://litebook.eu). Its about this `<section class="introWrapper">` thanks!

Comment: @hashbrown did you see my link? Thanks!

Comment: Read the **Grid System** from this page- http://getbootstrap.com/css/
Also do you mean something like this - http://www.mycookroom.ru/mywork/Elegant/Site/Image/ ?